# How to add new support to `expand-region`?

Tags: region

I'm trying to add new support to `expand-region`:

```lisp
(defun er/lisp-mode ()
  (interactive)
  "Enhancement for lisp like #'() ,@()"
  (when (looking-at "\\(\\(`,?\\)\\|\\('?,?\\)\\|\\(,?@?\\)\\|\\(#?'?\\)\\)?(")
    (cond ((er/looking-back-on-line ",\\|@\\|?\\|#\\|'\\|`")
           (backward-char 1)))
    (set-mark (point))
    (forward-list)
    (exchange-point-and-mark)))

(defun er/add-lisp-mode-expansions ()
  (make-variable-buffer-local 'er/try-expand-list)
  (setq er/try-expand-list (append er/try-expand-list '(er/lisp-mode))))

(use-package expand-region
  :ensure t
  :bind
  ("C-SPC" . er/expand-region)
  :hook ((lisp-mode slime-mode) . er/add-lisp-mode-expansions))
```

When I open the first `.lisp` file, it looks fine.
But after the first file, it doesn't work: `expand-region` will select all text of the entire buffer regardless of where I call `er/expand-region`.

When I look at `er/try-expand-list` in those buffers, it gives `(er/lisp-mode er/lisp-mode)` in lisp-mode buffers, and `nil` in buffers of other modes.

As far as I can see, it is `er/try-expand-list` that controls the behaviour of `er/expand-region`, so the problem is the wrong value of `er/try-expand-region`, which should be composed from the original value provided by `expand-region` with/without `er/lisp-mode` added, depending on the mode of the buffer.

How should I fix it?

Comment: I have updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: I tend to suspect that `use-package` declaration (but maybe because I don't use `use-package` so I don't know enough about it). But these things tend to add complexity and hide it at the same time, so there are subtle (and not so subtle) problems that crop up. If I were you, I'd get rid of that, try to set up everything "by hand" and only after that is working, would I go back to using `use-package`: the old technique of `divide-and-conquer`...

Comment: Thanks to your reply, I have already tried `(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'er/add-lisp-mode-expansions)`, but it performance like `use-package` too. Still don't know why that happen. I guess it may be caused by `(make-variable-buffer-local 'er/try-expand-list)`, but I'm not familiar with emacs lisp... If I call `er/add-lisp-mode-expansions` manually in each lisp-mode buffer, then it is okay, but once use `hook`, then it go wrong.

Comment: I would try to emulate one of the existing extensions, e.g. [Ivan Andrus's text expansions](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/blob/master/text-mode-expansions.el) although you probably want to find the most recent version of the package and go from there.

Comment: But in that way, I have to modify the source code of expand-region, which will be discard every update.

Comment: I think I have figure it out, I have to `(require 'expand-region)` first to make it work. But I still don't quiet understand. As far as I can see, `expan-region` won't been loaded at the meantime when I open a `lisp-mode` buffer, which cause the original `er/try-expand-list` to be `nil`. However, my own function to add support is already called, set the `er/try-expand-list` to `(er/lisp-mode)`.  What I don't understand is `make-variable-buffer-local` should retained that value buffer local, and other buffers shouldn't  been effect.

Comment: One way to make sure is to `(require 'expand-region)` early in your init file. That way it will *always* be available in the emacs session.